# "Possible lossy conversion from double to int" when trying to do 2 ^ variable

Tags: java, type-conversion, syntax-error, double

I am receiving the error "Possible lossy conversion from double to int" on the last line (error pointer pointing at the number "2"), when I am not attempting to convert anything from a double to an int. What am I missing?

```
System.out.println("This is the ancestry calculator. Enter number of generations: ");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int generations = input.nextInt();
int ancestors;
ancestors = Math.pow (2, generations);
```

Comment: `ancestors` is an `int`, and `Math.pow` returns a `double` .

Comment: `ancestors = 1 << generations;`.

Answer (score 1):

Math.pow() method returns a double value so if you need to assign it to ancestors you need to cast it.

```
   ancestors =(int) Math.pow (2, generations);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use any of the following:

```
double ancestors = Math.pow (2.0, generations)
```

or

```
int ancestors = (int) Math.pow (2, generations)
```